# When and why to use specific probability distributions?

Tags: distributions, modeling, references, poisson-distribution, gamma-distribution

I'm a graduate mathematics student and I've taken several courses on statistics, probability theory, stochastic processes and machine learning.

In all the textbooks I consulted and all the classes I've taken so far there is a great amount of mathematical detail and explanations regarding the simple concepts of the subject at hand. Specifically in statistics and machine learning there is often a lot of text on the description of the problem.

However, as soon as the problem is given they go straight to the model distributions. E.g. in our course on insurance mathematics estimating the insurance premium was done using a Poisson-Gamma distribution approach. But while there was a great deal of discussion on the (lack of) importance of the horsepower of the insured car, there was no explanation for why we would use the Poisson or Gamma distributions in our model.

Everywhere I look it is just assumed I already know which distribution is best fitted to model a specific problem.

Do you know any literature that explains in detail what the variety of modelling distributions we have represent and when and why to use them?

Comment: Maybe the books you are reading are too advanced: the most basic stats texts aim to give their readers facility in identifying appropriate probability models in common situations.  Most of the literature builds on this knowledge -- and therefore, assuming these fundamentals, perhaps do not provide the full explanations you seek.  A glance at some elementary textbooks might prove helpful.

Comment: whuber may have a point but  I  don't think that you're going to find that much of what you're looking for, even in less advanced textbooks.  Some frameworks do lend themselves to certain  possible distributions. For example, a counting process may o be distributed as poisson. When one is trying to estimate probabilities, the logistic is often usefl. In relability analysis, the Weibull is often used to model the time till breakdown. But, in general, I think thatt the notion of what distribution to use is often just assumed. Even good papers often make distributional assumptions.

Comment: I remember learning about the rationale behind using various distributions in my introduction to probability textbook. This would usually be done by justifying the distribution through some kind of real-world example, such as engineering applications, etc. Common examples are usually things like product/machine/device failures, manufacturing faults, etc. I think this is how most people gain their intuition/understanding for when a certain distribution is valid. [...]

Comment: [...] I'm not aware of any textbook that teaches this outright; I think most people just slowly learn this by studying the textbook and its examples/problems.